# Diff of two states of a string or array

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, string, diff

For a string and an array, I have an "old" state, and a "new" state (after some modifications).

I need to often send to the server (with AJAX/`XMLHttpRequest`) the changes, if possible in an efficient way (don't resend 200 KB of data if only one element in the array has changed/has been deleted/has been moved). Example:

```
var oldstate1 = 'hello how are you? very good and you? thanks for asking! this text will be removed.';
var newstate1 = 'hello how are you? very good and you? new text here. thanks for asking!';

var oldstate2 = [[1732, "item1"], [1732, "will be deleted"], [23, "will be moved"], [23, "hello"]];
var newstate2 = [[23, "will be moved"], [1732, "item1"], [23, "hello"], [126, "new item"]];
```

Of course, I could manually code a protocol between client and server with events such as `delete`, `insert`, `move`, `update`, etc. and send these events with AJAX, and the server would update its database accordingly. But this is quite tedious to do correctly.

**Question: is there a more clever way to encode only changes between `oldstate` and `newstate` of a big string or array with Javascript?** in a way that can easily be decoded on backend, running Python.

Something similar to a `diff/patch` algorithm for strings or arrays, understood between JS (client-side) and Python (back-end).

Note:

- a solution for strings might be enough, the "array case" would be covered by the "string case" with `JSON.stringigy(...)`
- related but doesn't solve directly the problem: [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: A simple but inelegant method would be to send Javascript text of the operations you perform on the array, then run the JS in a new script tag

Comment: @CertainPerformance Interesting indeed! Unfortunately the backend doesn't run Node.js, so I couldn't run the same JS operations there.

Comment: You wouldn't have to *run* them, but you would have to be able to dynamically *create* the JS strings from the operations you perform in Python. Depends on the sort of manipulations you need to do, might be easy, might be near impossible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865869/how-to-find-difference-between-two-array-using-lodash-underscore-in-nodejs

Comment: @Zydnar Yes this is similar to [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript), but at the end you have to manually recode a protocol to make use of these array differences of `arr1` and `arr2`, and differences of `arr2` and `arr1`, so that the server knows where to insert these differences / what to delete. The question here was: is there an ready-to-use tool to do that?

Comment: So what you wan't is merge two arrays, rewrite (update) already existing and delete what have been deleted? If so maybe try https://lodash.com/docs/#update

Comment: Maybe @Zydnar; could you post an example with `oldstate2` and `newstate2` that I included in the question? It would be interesting to see how it works with lodash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably possible with no third-party tool (if so, feel free to post another answer).

After further research, I found this project: [diff-match-patch](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch) and particularly this [example](https://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/demos/patch.html).

> Originally built in 2006 to power Google Docs, this library is now available in C++, C#, Dart, Java, JavaScript, Lua, Objective C, and Python.

```js
var oldstate1 = "hello how are you? very good and you? blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla. thanks for asking! this text will be removed.";
var newstate1 = "hello how are you? very good and you? blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla.new text here. thanks for asking!";
var dmp = new diff_match_patch();
var diff = dmp.diff_main(oldstate1, newstate1);
dmp.diff_cleanupSemantic(diff);
console.log(dmp.diff_toDelta(diff))    
// =138 +new text here. =19 -27
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/diff_match_patch/20121119/diff_match_patch.js"></script>
```

This `delta` + `oldstate1` can then be used server-side, with Python, to reconstruct the `newstate1`:

```
import diff_match_patch as dmp_module
dmp = dmp_module.diff_match_patch()

oldstate1 = "hello how are you? very good and you? blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla. thanks for asking! this text will be removed."
delta = "=138\t+new text here.\t=19\t-27"
patch = dmp.patch_make(oldstate1, dmp.diff_fromDelta(oldstate1, delta))
newstate1 = dmp.patch_apply(patch, oldstate1)[0]
print(newstate1)
```

---

See also [this issue](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch/issues/84).

Comment: I was going to suggest looking for something like this when I saw the question.  I was sure it *had* to exist.  But note that you probably need something akin to commit/version numbers to apply this properly.  If multiple clients edit the same data, or if one does multiple times, there is a real possibility of getting out of sync.

Comment: That's right @ScottSauyet, I just started to implement it using a commit number. If one user pushes with a too old commit number, I display a message "You are using an old version of this document, please refresh the page". It's works for now. PS: it's interesting to see that Google had to develop such a library for Google Docs needs back in 2006!